# Java appending to file with getClass().getResource("something").toString() is not workinh?

Tags: java

Working directory in Eclipse looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to append to `happyPreview.scm` and have to call this method from `SpeechPreview.java`. I tried:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getClass().getResource("previews" + File.separator + "happyPreview.scm").toString(), true)));
```

I thought this would work since they're all in the same 'bash' package but it doesn't work? Nothing is appending!

Answer (score 0):

class.getResource() -> root is the project folder, it is not the class current package folder..
try this

```
getClass().getResource("/bash/previews/happyPreview.scm")
```

Comment: I  just tried this (with the .toString() method), doesn't work.

Comment: see in your eclipse project bin folder the file exists, i suspect it is not copied over..

Comment: I just looked in bin/bash/previews, the happyPreview.scm file is there

Comment: edited answer try this getClass().getResource("/bash/previews/happyPreview.scm")
starts with / which we are missing before

Answer (score 0):

You can't *write* to a class resource, only read, and even then, only streaming.

This is because your code will be packaged in a .jar file, that is on the classpath. The deployed .jar file is read-only. Sure, it's not packaged in a .jar file while developing, but it will be when you are done and need to deploy it.

If you want your code to ship with a default/initial resource, and update it, the updated file must be stored elsewhere. When next you try to read it, you first check that other location, and if not found, *then* you load from resource file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I tried to move the happyPreview.scm file outside of the source folder, was this what you meant?

Comment: Sure, that'll work. Just don't write to a resource retrieved using `getResource()`. There's a reason it's a `URL`, and not a `File`.